# Executing SQL CREATE statements via CRON in order

Tags: apache-nifi

I want to execute 5 SQL `CREATE TABLE` statements in a specific order with Apache Nifi. Once the first table has been successfully created, I want the second processor to create the next table and so on.

I have been able to execute `CREATE` statements with a `PutSQL`-processor, but I am having trouble to get it running as a CRON job because `PutSQL` requires an upstream connection which I don't have for the *first* of my 5 `PutSQL`-processors. The other 4 run after the previous finished which works great.

Is there a trick so that the first `PutSQL`-processor doesn't need an upstream connection, or is there a "dummy"-processor which I can use to send a CRON/timed success-message to my first `PutSQL`-processor which then starts working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use ExecuteSQL for which the incoming relationship is optional.

https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.12.1/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.ExecuteSQL/index.html

If you want to use PutSQL, you can use GenerateFlowFile on a CRON schedule to kick  a single flow file out at the specific time to trigger PutSQL.

Comment: Ahhh, `GenerateFlowFile` was what I was looking for! Thanks!